# How to extract words after second colon?

Tags: ms-access, formula

I have tried this one,
Mid([Tom]![Subject];InStr([Tom]![Subject];":")+1)

However, this extracts only the text after the first colon.

I need to extract the text after the second colon.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use first parameter of InStr function:

```
Mid([Tom]![Subject];InStr(InStr([Tom]![Subject];":")+1,[Tom]![Subject];":")+1)
```